# Why does this code return a list index error?

Tags: python, indexing

Basically it's supposed to take a set of coordinates and return a list of coordinates of it's neighbors. However, when it hits here:

```
if result[i][0] < 0 or result[i][0] >= board.dimensions:
    result.pop(i)
```

when `i` is 2, it gives me an out of index error. I can manage to have it print result[2][0] but at the if statement it throws the errors. Why is this happening?

```
def neighborGen(row,col,board):
    """
    returns lists of coords of neighbors, in order of up, down, left, right
    """

    result = []
    result.append([row-1 , col])
    result.append([row+1 , col])
    result.append([row , col-1])
    result.append([row , col+1])

     #prune off invalid neighbors (such as (0,-1), etc etc)
     for i in range(len(result)): 
        if result[i][0] < 0 or result[i][0] >= board.dimensions:
            result.pop(i)
        if result[i][1] < 0 or result[i][1] >= board.dimensions:
            result.pop(i)

    return result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the indexes to iterate over from the list, and then you proceed to remove elements from the list. Eventually you're going to hit an index that no longer exists. Use a list comprehension to filter instead.

```
result = [entry for entry in result if entry[0] >= 0 and
  entry[0] < board.dimensions and entry[1] >= 0 and
  entry[1] < board.dimensions]
```

Comment: Should I replace the entire for loop with this code? I'm having a little trouble understanding the syntax.

Comment: Yes, it replaces the entire for loop. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Thank you very much for saving me! Also, the link to the pydocs page is an awesome touch. Have an awesome day.

Comment: Actually, sorry for the late followup, but how would I be able to replace the invalid entry with None instead of just removing it?

Comment: `[entry if ... else None for entry in result]`

Comment: I'm getting syntax errors. Care to clarify? 
Edit: Quick thing, I'm using python 2.6 as a requirement for this project (something with certain libraries not being ported) so I'm not sure if that has something to do with it.

Comment: The big condition replaces the `...`.

Comment: I assumed it was that way but it is giving me the syntax error saying there is something wrong with else being there.

Comment: It is now reading:
     result = [entry for entry in result if entry[0] >= 0 and
              entry[0] < board.dim and entry[1] >= 0 and
              entry[1] < board.dim else None for entry in result]

Comment: That doesn't match what I gave you.

Comment: I'm sorry, in the op I just changed .dim to .dimensions to clarify what it was for readers. The actual code is board.dim

Comment: Got it finally. Thanks for pushing me to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 2):

During the `for` loop, you are popping elements which decreases the size of `result`. Yet, `i` will still go from 0 to 4.

Answer (score 2):

If you pop off an element, then it's no longer in the list - but your index doesn't move, so it's now pointing to the next element. Say you pop off two elements... your list size after that would be 2, but the `for` loop is still going to try to go to 4.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thank you very much. Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
def neighborGen(row,col,board):
    """
    returns lists of coords of neighbors, in order of up, down, left, right
    """

    return [
        x for x in (
            [row-1 , col], [row+1 , col], [row , col-1], [row , col+1]
        ) 
        if x[0] >= 0 and x[0] < board.dimensions and
        x[1] >= 0 and x[1] < board.dimensions
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension to remove the invalid points. For example:

```
result = [coords for coords in result
          if all(0 <= c < board.dimension for c in coords)]
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, the indexes of the remaining elements change when you remove elements from the middle of the list. To avoid problems, you could process the elements from last index to first:

```
for i in range(len(result)-1, -1, -1): 
   ...
```

Now, when the current element is removed, only indexes for already processed elements change. Since those elements are already processed and don't need to be accessed again, it doesn't matter if their indexes are no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to avoid this kind of off-the-board testing is to have a buffer zone of one or two rows/columns at the edges of the board. The board positions would have, as well as the usual values of "empty" or which side owned the square with what type of piece, a special "invalid" code. This would usually be coupled with a board representation as a ONE-dimensional array.

For example, chess would use an array of size 120 (10 columns x 12 rows). You need a margin of 2 to cater for knights ... 2 rows at each end but you need only one vertical margin as it can be shared.

E.g.

```
KNIGHT_DELTAS = (-21, -19, -12, -8, 8, 12, 19, 21)
# I have a knight at "currpos"; what are its options?
for delta in KNIGHT_DELTAS:
    newpos = currpos + delta
    target = board[newpos]
    if target & EMPTY:
        can_move_to(newpos)
    elif target & OTHER_TEAM:
        can_capture(at=newpos, captured_piece=target & PIECE_VALUE)
    else:
        # Either off the board or occupied by MY_TEAM.
        # Notice that we didn't even need to test explicitly for "off the board".
        pass
```